# UPDATE form SELECT to autoincrement a column, is it possible?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can I UPDATE from a SELECT rather than having to loop though results in code and do single updates? Like:

```
UPDATE player_squad SET player_position = players.n WHERE player_id = players.player_id FROM (SELECT INCREMENT() as n, players.* FROM players ..) as players;
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but hopefully it's apparent what I'm trying to do.

Database tables:

```
player_squad(player_team_id, player_id, team_id)
player(player_id, name, age, etc)
```

I'm trying to avoid having to iterate through thousands of players and perform single updates on them:

```
// loop through players
var players = .. // SELECT * FROM players ..
for n in players.size():
  var player = players[n]
  .. // UPDATE player_squad SET player_position = n WHERE player_id = player.player_id;
```

Comment: What is `INCREMENT()`? Is it just an arbitrary sequence of unique numbers or is it based on any logic of ordered rows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using a subselect, using the `IN` operator:

```
UPDATE player_squad
SET player_position = players.n
WHERE player_id IN (
    SELECT players.player_id as n
    FROM players
);
```

You will need to append your filter into the subselect if you do not want to use the full table in your subselect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in a subquery of the table `player` to assign a unique number to each player and with the [`UPDATE ... FROM ...`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax (available since version 3.33.0) join it to the table `player_squad`:

```
UPDATE player_squad AS ps
SET player_position = p.rn
FROM ( 
  SELECT player_id, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY player_id) AS rn
  FROM player
) AS p
WHERE p.player_id = ps.player_id;
```

Or, with a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS ( 
  SELECT player_id, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY player_id) AS rn
  FROM player
)
UPDATE player_squad AS ps
SET player_position = c.rn
FROM cte AS c
WHERE c.player_id = ps.player_id;
```